# Replacing a single backslash with a double backslash in R

Tags: r

I want to create a function to automatically correct single backslashes to double backslashes since R gives an error if you copy paste a path due to a single backslash. But when I try this, it gives an error:

```
> x<-gsub("\", "\\", "pak\istan")

Error: unexpected '\\' in "x<-gsub("\","\"
```

Then I tried this and got the same error again:

```
> x<-gsub("\", "\\", "pak\istan", fixed=TRUE)

Error: unexpected '\\' in "x<-gsub("\","\"
```

How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In the `pattern` argument of `gsub` you need to escape the backslash character, cf. `gsub`'s documentation. That is, it needs to be a double backslash.

Furthermore, the backslash in "pak\istan" also needs to be escaped:

```
gsub("\\", "\\", "pak\\istan", fixed=TRUE)
```